# Strategy - Drawing a 'correct tick/check mark' to perform an action

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

I am looking for a strategy or guidance to get the functionality. I have a an app that does simple math. A math sum such as "4+4 = 8" appears, and if the user agrees they draw a "tick" or "correction mark" (similar to the Nike tick) or if they dont agree they draw an "X".

I know how to draw however what is the technique to detect if either the tick or the X has been drawn? Or simpler, just detect if the "tick" is indeed a tick.

It is just guidance and/or direction to find a solution that will recognise these using UIGestureRecognizer.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more This shows how to create custom gestures with UIGesturerecognizer

Comment: @Putz1103 thanks very much, this is a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom gestures are possible using UIGestureRecognizer.  I'm not sure how to do it as I never have before.  But here is a good tutorial on the different options available.

[Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)

[Also this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891625/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-custom-tickle-uigesturerecognizer)

[And this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753533/uigesturerecognizer-custom-gestures)